# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'roomID 'and 'sotreId'. Either include them or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not using socketData function outside the useEffect and then also, i am getting warning.I want to remove this warning without using // eslint-disable-next-line.
I am getting roomID and sotreID from parent Component from server and socket is the local server url

```javascript
    useEffect(() => {
        const socketData = () => {
            console.log('sotreId', sotreId);
            setReceiverID(sotreId);
            socketRef.current = socket;
            console.log(socket);
            socketRef.current.emit('mobileNumber', roomID);
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }).then(stream => {
                backgroundVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("background error", error)
            });
            socketRef.current.on("yourID", (id) => {
                console.log(id);
                setYourID(id);
            })
            socketRef.current.on("allUsers", (users) => {
                console.log(users);
                setUsers(users);
            })
        }
        socketData();
    }, []);
```

Comment: It gives you warning because your function depends on `roomID` and `sotreId`, so you should pass them as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should add both `roomId` and `storeId` in the array of dependencies like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
const socketData = () => {
    console.log('sotreId', sotreId);
    setReceiverID(sotreId);
    socketRef.current = socket;
    console.log(socket);
    socketRef.current.emit('mobileNumber', roomID);
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }).then(stream => {
        backgroundVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("background error", error)
    });
    socketRef.current.on("yourID", (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        setYourID(id);
    })
    socketRef.current.on("allUsers", (users) => {
        console.log(users);
        setUsers(users);
    })
}
socketData();
}, [roomeId, storeId]);
```

Comment: I am new to react hooks.Is it possible to remove warning without adding dependencies in dependency array.

Comment: you can wrap the socketData in a usecallback then call it in the useeffect, check this article https://betterprogramming.pub/why-eslint-hates-your-useeffect-dependencies-react-js-560fcac0b1f
but i think the linter will show warning in the useCallback